# RN elements: bind list onpress

Tags: react-native

Relatively new to React Native; and in the following example code I want to create a list with a bound `onPress` function. Unfortunately, pressing an item will allways print the last item, which is "Suze" in this case.

```
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
...

onPress(name){
  console.log(name);
}

renderPerson(person) {
  return (< ListItem
    key={person._id}
    title={person.name}
    onPress={() => this.onPress(person.name)}
  />)
}


renderPeople = () => {
  people =  [{"_id": 1, "name": "Eric"},
             {"_id":2, "name": "Paul"},
             {"_id":3, "name": "Suze"}]
  return people.map((p) => (
    this.renderPerson(p)
  ))
}

render() {
  return (
    <List>
      {this.renderPeople()}
    </List>
  )
}
```

**update**

Included constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.renderPerson = this.renderPerson.bind(this);
  this.renderPeople = this.renderPeople.bind(this);
}
```

But still the last item is printed

Comment: Try `people.map(p => this.renderPerson(p))`. Remove your `return` before `people.map`

Comment: list items are not rendered

Comment: In your constructor have you used `bind` for your functions?
`this.renderPerson = this.renderPerson.bind(this)
this.renderPeople = this.renderPeople.bind(this)`

Comment: unfortunately this has no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried your example, and it's working as expected so you must be missing something in the code you pasted.

That being said, for readability's sake, I would write it like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderPerson = this.renderPerson.bind(this);
    this.renderPeople = this.renderPeople.bind(this);
  }

  renderPerson(person) {
    return (<ListItem
      key={person._id}
      title={person.name}
      onPress={() => this.onPress(person.name)}
    />);
  }

  onPress(name) {
    console.log(name);
  }

  renderPeople(people) {
    return people.map((p) => this.renderPerson(p));
  }

  render() {
    const people =  [{"_id": 1, "name": "Eric"},
               {"_id":2, "name": "Paul"},
               {"_id":3, "name": "Suze"}];
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <List>
          {this.renderPeople(people)}
        </List>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: yes you're right, it works perfectly! the constructor bind did it